# Iterating over string/strlen with umlauted characters

Tags: c, xcode, macos, character-encoding

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725124/accented-umlauted-characters-in-c) . I succeeded in implementing the algorithm for checking umlauted characters. The next problem comes from iterating over all characters in a string. I do this like so:

```
int main()
{
    char* str = "Hej du kalleåäö";
    printf("length of str: %d", strlen(str));

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", to_morse(str[i]));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that, because of the umlauted characters, it prints 18, and also makes the to_morse function fail (ignoring these characters). The toMorse method accepts an unsigned char as a parameter.  What would be the best way to solve this? I know I can check for the umlaut character here instead of the letterNr function but I don't know if that would be a pretty/logical solution.

Comment: Have you tried the solution described in this reply to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725124/accented-umlauted-characters-in-c/1725169#1725169

Comment: @Carl Smotricz is right: libraries are your friend here.  UTF-8 is clever, which means its also not trivial to get right.  (Little about Unicode is easy to get right: human languages are loaded with special cases).  May I suggest looking at GLib's `g_utf8_strlen`?  It doesn't solve your immediate problem but you will learn a lot about this.  http://git.gnome.org/cgit/glib/tree/glib/gutf8.c

Comment: @Miroslav: Yes, I tried that solution, but it gave me the double prints.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you'd store the string in a `wchar_t` and use something like `ansi_strlen` to get the length of it - that would give you the number of printed characters as opposed to the number of bytes you stored.

You really shouldn't be implementing UTF or Unicode or whatever multibyte character handling yourself - there are libraries for that sort of thing.

Comment: I am not familiar with the libraries (coming from the Java world). I implemented Michal Sznajder's hack for these chars so I was hoping there would be a solution similar to this as well.

Comment: This may be all you need: http://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2009/10/more_about_wchar_t/

Comment: I agree with this.  See the comment about GLib's `g_utf8_strlen` under the question.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, Cocoa is a solution -  note the use of "%C" in NSLog - that's an unichar (16-bit Unicode character):

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main()
{
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
        NSString * input = @"Hej du kalleåäö";

        printf("length of str: %d", [input length]);
        int i=0;
        for (i = 0; i < [input length]; i++)
        {
                NSLog(@"%C", [input characterAtIndex:i]);
        }

        [pool release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: What locale are you using?

If you are going to **iterating** over a string, don't bother with getting its length with `strlen`. Just iterate until you see a `NUL` character:

```
char *p = str;
while(*p != '\0') {
    printf("%c\n", *p);
    ++p;
}
```

As for the umlauted characters and such, are they UTF-8? If the string is multi-byte, you could do something like this:

```
size_t n = strlen(str);
char *p = str;
char *e = p + n;
while(*p != '\0') {
    wchar_t wc;
    int l = mbtowc(&wc, p, e - p);
    if(l <= 0) break;
    p += l;
    /* do whatever with wc which is now in wchar_t form */
}
```

I honestly don't know if `mbtowc` will simply return `-1` if it encounters a `NUL` in the middle of a MB character. If it does, you could just pass `MB_CUR_MAX` instead of `e - p` and do away with the `strlen` call. But I have a feeling this is **not** the case.

Comment: I'm not sure... completely new to thinking about charsets. As somebody asked in the previous question, it looks like the input is UTF-8 but the codeset is ASCII...

Comment: Also, your code gives an error in the line  p += mbtowc(&wc, p, n - p);
Invalid operands to binary -

Comment: whoops, fixed that for ya. That's what I get for posting without compiling.

Comment: Can you please explain this further? If I print to_morse(*p) it gives me lots of invalid morse codes.

Comment: well that code assumes that the string is multibyte (like utf-8). But also, look at the comment.. it says "do whatever with wc..." THAT is the multibyte character converted to a wchar_t.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
for (int i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; ++i){
    //do something with str[i]
}
```

Strings in C are terminated with '\0'. So it is possible to check for the end of the string like that.

Comment: Here's what I did, and surprisingly works so far:
` //loop until we get a NUL character
 for (int i = 0; str[i]!='\0'; ++i)
 {
  unsigned char letter = str[i];
  
  //if we have an umlaut, read the next char instead
  if (0xC3 == letter)
   printf("%s ", to_morse(str[++i]));
  else
   printf("%s ", to_morse(str[i]));
 }
 ’
Then I removed the check for umlaut characters in letter_Nr.